# How do I add x-api-key header in RestSharp v107+ to add API Key?

Tags: restsharp

I'm trying to call a secure web API using RestSharp v110.  I need to add an API Key to the request by adding the x-api-key header.  There's many examples of using RestSharp.AddHeader but, as of v107, it appears RestSharp removed the IRestRequest interface along with this method.  See https://restsharp.dev/v107/#reference

The documentation only lists Extension as an alternative.  What extension do I need to use to add a header to my RestRequest?

I've successfully used the new version on other APIs.  Just need some help with adding a header.

Answer (score 0):

The `AddHeader` method is available for `RestRequest` as it was before.

```
/// <summary>
/// Adds a header to the request. RestSharp will try to separate request and content headers when calling the resource.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="request">Request instance</param>
/// <param name="name">Header name</param>
/// <param name="value">Header value</param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static RestRequest AddHeader(this RestRequest request, string name, string value) {
```

There are multiple overloads, which allow you to use a string or a value type as the value, as well as add or update headers, or add multiple headers.

Based on your question I suspect you are looking for ready-made examples, but the first place you might want to look at is IntelliSense of your IDE. Second place would be the `RestRequest` class and its extensions in RestSharp repository.

Comment: Thanks Alexey, you pointed me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

As the documentation stated, `AddHeader` has moved to an extension.  I simply had to add a using statement for `RestSharp.RestRequestExtensions` and then I was able to use:

```
request.AddHeader("x-api-key", "my key");
```